# Bind Aidl Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, aidl

I defined a public service with AIDL called **APIAidlInterface**. I'm now wondering if I can bind this service inside the application ? Which means the client will be in the same process as server.

Here is my simple implemented code:

```
APIAidlInterface apiAidlService = null;
private ServiceConnection APIServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        apiAidlService = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        apiAidlService = APIAidlInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }
};
```

Bind service:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, APIAidlInterface.class);
boolean isAPIBound = context.bindService(intent, APIServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
if (isAPIBound) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Connected to API");
} else {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Connot connect to API");
}
```

The result of **isAPIBound** always return **false**. So I'm not sure that means I cannot bind a AIDL service from the same process?

BTW, I also create a test App. In the test App, I can bind the service with the **implicit intent** like: `Intent intent = new Intent(APIAidlInterface.class.getName());`. When I did it with explicit intent like `Intent intent = new Intent(context, APIAidlInterface.class);`. It said cannot find the APIAidlInterface.

====================== More Info =========================

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service android:name="com.example.APIAidlService"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.APIAidlInterface" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

In **APIAidlService**

```
private final APIAidlInterfaceImpt apiAidlInterfaceImpt = new APIAidlInterfaceImpt(this);

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return apiAidlInterfaceImpt;
}
```

Comment: `new Intent(context, APIAidlInterface.class)` <= this is wrong, you should use the real service class ... of course if you wana use it outside the app which define this service you have to know the service name directly (the one which is defined in AndroidManifest of app which contains this service) ... `Intent(APIAidlInterface.class.getName())` <= this is wrong as Intent with one string param takes this string as action

Comment: for outside the app which define the service use `Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.package", "com.example.package.RealServiceClassNameWhichIsDefinedInsideManifestNotInterfaceClass"));`

Comment: Did you implement `onBind()` in your `Service`?

Comment: Thanks! I think maybe my problem comes from the architecture. Because it doesn't work for me. In face, I defined a class **AidlInterfaceImpt** which extend **AidlInterface.Stub** with the constructor `AidlInterfaceImpt(AidlService service)`. The **AidlService** is the service which is defined in Manifest.

Comment: Yes, I implemented onBind function which return aidlInterfaceImpt

Comment: As I wrote you should use com.example.APIAidlService as class in componentname

Comment: @Selvin it works! Thanks for your answer